# How to use run deck service from local browser using up address?

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, centos7, rundeck

I have installed `rundeck` in docker using ec2 instance.
When I run the image and start `rundeck`. It's fine.

> Lynx http:localhost:4440

Us able to show `rundeck` dashboard.

But, how can I access this `rundeck` from Windows browser?

I tried using address but connection refused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access this from outside for your setup, you might have to ensure the following things:

1. Ensure that host server (ec2) is forwarding ports to the `docker` container. You should have used `-p` or `-ports` when launching the container for this. 
   Test: From your EC2 instance, you should be able to access: `http://localhost:4440`
2. Ensure you have a public IP assigned to your EC2. You should be able to see that from your aws ec2 console: http://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2
3. Ensure that your `security group(s)` for that instance has `InBound` connections to accept 4440 from your IP or rest of the world.

After this, your http://:4440 should work.
I hope I got your question correct.

Let me know how it goes,

Thanks,

- Anoop